Identify SMT diodes
Some more reverse-engineering happening.  Can some kind soul please help identify the following parts, please?

Text appears to be "M2W"

The smaller package appears to be a SOT-23 device.


Could we get some dimensions on these parts?

The first one is probably MA720 single Schottky. And the second one might be some TVS diode (SMC package).

The bigger package is a Littelfuse unidirectional TVS diode, SMCJ series.

the above is a screen grab, showing marking "GFG", of a Littelfuse SMCJ series TVS diode datasheet.
The smaller package does indeed seem to be a MA720 , but I take no credit, all I did was look it up based on comment from user "Matt".

So Very Many Thanks!
